# Hinting at Steganography

Tags: game-design, puzzle

I'm working on an ARG which will be implemented mostly through a standard website. I'd like to give some of the images on the site steganographic content (hidden content stored in an image, e.g. an 8 color image of the same dimensions stored as even and odd color values in the pixels). Technologically, this is fairly easy to do. However, I'm having trouble figuring out a subtle way to hint at the presence of this content. The effect itself is invisible to the naked eye, and nobody just randomly checks for this kind of thing. What can I do to draw players' forensic attention to these images, while still maintaining an amount of subtlety (i.e. something that doesn't make it *glaringly* obvious)?

Comment: Hi, not sure if you're still interested, but I wrote a blog post on image steganography a while ago. One of the things I talk about is flaws in the steganography. You can read it here: http://hasherr.com/steganography-pros-cons-variants-problems-and/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to "hide" an obvious message that then gets people looking for a more subtle one. Like a breadcrumb to lead them down the path.

For instance, pick a line or block somewhere in the image, and use the high bits in that patch to encode a short ascii string like "LOOK CLOSER" or a phrase significant to your game (like a name or date). This will be visible to the eye as a line or block of static.

While a naive viewer might assume it's a compression glitch or data corruption, someone familiar with ARGs/steganography will know to check whether the pattern of bright & dark pixels means something. They can do this by eye just by zooming in and entering the bits into a binary-to-ascii converter. The obvious message then confirms that they're on the right path, but can still go deeper, using image editing software to look for more subtly encoded information.

You can also try choosing the two images so that they have a "tell." If the overlying image has a patch that's all one flat colour, and the underlying image has some well-defined edges that cross this area, this will often be just barely noticeable - the eye is much better at spotting structure like edges than slight variations in dithering.

One more way would be to use more of the low bits, to increase the interference with the overlying image until it's noticeable. To keep the underlying image from being immediately visible, you can scramble it. Choose an underlying image width that's relatively prime to the overlying images's width, and encode each row one after another, wrapping around to the next line whenever you hit the edge of the main image. This scrambles the image so that pixels that should be adjacent vertically, aren't.

If the image and widths are chosen well, this should look like coloured static all over the main image - but static with too much repetition to be random, again cueing a sharp observer to look at the data. They then have an extra puzzle of figuring out the right stride to re-align thr rows of the hidden image.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to somehow implant a reference to your ARG in the image. A photo-shopped in poster on the wall with the logo for your game on it in a photo that otherwise shouldn't reference the game. But more subtle than that, make the picture somehow disconcerting. For reference look at paintings by [Magritte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Magritte) and you'll know what I mean about disconcerting (you might want to be more mild than him though). Or look at pictures for the "When you see it.." meme for ideas on things that you'd glance over but disturb you if you noticed the details.

Even something like the size of the image can be a give away. When playing cryptographic games lots of people carefully go though the code of suspect web pages and they'll have in text the dimensions of an image. If say 31 is an important number and an image width turns out to be a multiple of that, people will look closer. Putting protection on the image so you can't just right click and save to download will also draw interest. Having very crisp graphics everywhere but then uploading one with higher compression all of a sudden will be suspicious. Fiddle with the metadata so if they download all the images on the site and compare them they'll notice some either have additional info or are stripped of it.

Replacing an image with something new will draw attention, especially if that image was part of the navigation for the site. Misspell something, screw up some grammar, leave off a period. Give conflicting information about an image eg, the time stamp says May 12th but it was posted on May 11th, or there's something going on that happened on the 13th, not the 12th.

These are just some suggestions. I'm not really sure who your target audience is, or what kind of feel you're going for, so it's hard to be more specific than general ideas about how one might go about something like this. But in all likeliness you won't need to hint much at all, just introduce your players to increasingly more complex puzzles and someone is bound to wonder if there's anything hidden in your image files.

Answer (score -1):

One way I know is changing pixel colour to reflect a binary value.

Example 0 for an even coloured value and 1 for odd coloured value for every pixel. Changing images just one bit of it's coloured value tricks the eye if you use a multiple coloured picture/image.

The program then arranges the bit values taken from certain positions in the image to create a hidden message.

Example: A jpg picture for example can hold 256 color per pixel. If say the target pixel has value of 101 and you need to change it to odd number then you change it to 100. You may need to change 8 pixel to create 1 character cause 8 bits = 1 byte and 1 byte should be enough to reflect one ASCII character.

Comment: This is how to do it. I'm looking more for how to tell someone that it's been done, but discreetly.